# Client/Server Chat in JavaFx is working but console shows error

Tags: java, javafx

I have built a client/chat server with multiple users which works, but the console always shows the same error message despite the fact that the program works.

Could you run it and help me figure out what may be the problem?

server code:

```
public class Server extends Application{

private final static int PORT=8000;
private TextArea ta=new TextArea();
private Socket socket;
private ServerSocket serverSocket;
private LinkedList<HandleClientTraffic> serverToOtherClients=new LinkedList<>();
private Vector<Integer> v=null;


public void start(Stage primaryStage){
    ta.setEditable(false);
    Scene scene=new Scene(new ScrollPane(ta),450,200);
    primaryStage.setTitle("Server");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
    primaryStage.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
    primaryStage.setOnCloseRequest(new EventHandler<WindowEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(WindowEvent event) {
            Platform.exit();
            System.exit(0); 
        }
    });


    new Thread(()->{
        try {
            serverSocket=new ServerSocket(PORT);
            Platform.runLater( () ->
            { ta.appendText("MultiThreadServer started at " 
              + new Date() + '\n');
            });

            while(true){
                socket=serverSocket.accept();
                Platform.runLater(()->{
                    InetAddress inetAddress=socket.getInetAddress();
                    ta.appendText("Connection from Socket[addr="+inetAddress.getHostAddress()+
                            ".port="+inetAddress.getHostName()+".localport="+PORT+"] at "+new Date());
                });

                HandleClientTraffic t= new HandleClientTraffic(socket);
                serverToOtherClients.add(t);
                t.start();
            }




        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }).start();


}

class HandleClientTraffic extends Thread{
    private Socket socket;
    private String userName="";
    private ObjectOutputStream outputToClient;
    ObjectInputStream inputFromClient;
    boolean connect=true;

    public HandleClientTraffic(Socket socket){
        this.socket=socket;
    }


    public void run() {
        try {
            outputToClient=new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            inputFromClient=new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

            //Get name
            userName=(String)inputFromClient.readObject();
            ta.appendText("\n"+userName+" enter the chat\n");

            for(int i=0;i<serverToOtherClients.size();i++){
                serverToOtherClients.get(i).updateContant();
            }

            while(true){
                int sizeIndicator=(Integer)inputFromClient.readObject();
                String getText=(String)inputFromClient.readObject();
                if(sizeIndicator!=0){ 
                    v=new Vector<Integer>();
                    for(int i=0;i<sizeIndicator;i++){
                        v.addElement((Integer)inputFromClient.readObject());
                    }
                    Platform.runLater(()->{
                        ta.appendText(userName+":"+getText+"\n");
                        for(int i=0;i<v.size();i++){
                            int indexSend=v.get(i);
                            HandleClientTraffic a=serverToOtherClients.get(indexSend);
                            try{
                                if(a.connect){
                                    a.outputToClient.writeObject(userName+":"+getText+"\n");
                                }
                            }catch(Exception e){
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        }

                    });
                }else{ //0=to all
                    Platform.runLater(()->{
                        ta.appendText(userName+":"+getText+"\n");
                        for(int i=serverToOtherClients.size();--i>=0;){
                            HandleClientTraffic a=serverToOtherClients.get(i);
                            try{
                                if(a.connect){
                                    a.outputToClient.writeObject(userName+":"+getText+"\n");
                                }
                            }catch(Exception e){
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        }

                    });


                }



            }


        }catch(SocketException ss){
            try{
                connect=false;
                String theName=userName;
                socket.close();
                Platform.runLater(()->{
                    ta.appendText(theName+" has left the chat!\n");
                });
                for(int i=0;i<serverToOtherClients.size();i++){
                    HandleClientTraffic a=serverToOtherClients.get(i);
                        if(a.connect){
                        a.outputToClient.writeObject(theName+" has left the chat!\n");}
                }
            }catch(IOException ioe){

            }
        }
        catch(ClassNotFoundException er){
            System.out.println("class not found problem,in server class");
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("input or output stream problem,in server class");
        }



    }//run

    public String getUserName(){
        return userName;
    }
    public ObjectOutputStream getOutputToClient(){
        return outputToClient;
    }
    public ObjectInputStream getInputFromClient(){
        return inputFromClient;
    }
    public void updateContant(){

        try{//Get current online users
        outputToClient.writeObject("#");//sign
        outputToClient.flush();
        outputToClient.writeObject(serverToOtherClients.size());
        outputToClient.flush();
        for(int i=0;i<serverToOtherClients.size();i++){
            outputToClient.writeObject(serverToOtherClients.get(i).userName);
            outputToClient.flush();}
        }catch(IOException ef){}
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}


}
```

client code:

```
public class Client extends Application{
private TextField tfName=new TextField();
private TextField tf=new TextField();
private TextArea ta=new TextArea();
private Socket socket;
private ObjectInputStream inputFromServer=null;
private ObjectOutputStream outputFromClient=null;
private ListView<String> listView=new ListView<String>();
private String myName;

public void start(Stage primaryStage){
    BorderPane mainPane=new BorderPane();
    ta.setEditable(false);
    tf.setEditable(false);
    listView.setPrefSize(100,70);
    listView.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);
    GridPane gridPane=new GridPane();
    gridPane.add(new Label("Name"), 0, 0);
    gridPane.add(new Label("Enter text"), 0, 1);
    gridPane.add(tfName, 1, 0);
    gridPane.add(tf, 1, 1);
    gridPane.add(new Label(" Send to\n specified users "),2,0);
    gridPane.add(new Label("Current online users"),3,0);
    gridPane.add(listView,3,1);
    mainPane.setTop(gridPane);
    mainPane.setCenter(new ScrollPane(ta));

    Scene scene=new Scene(mainPane);
    primaryStage.setTitle("Client");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
    primaryStage.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
    primaryStage.setOnCloseRequest(new EventHandler<WindowEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(WindowEvent event) {
            Platform.exit();
            System.exit(0); 
        }
    });


    tfName.setOnAction(e->{
        try {
            outputFromClient.writeObject(tfName.getText().trim());
            outputFromClient.flush();
            myName=tfName.getText().trim();
            ta.appendText("Server:Hi "+tfName.getText().trim()+"!\n");
            tfName.setText("");
            if(!tf.isEditable()){
            tf.setEditable(true);
            tfName.setEditable(false);
            }


        } catch (Exception e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

    });

    tf.setOnAction(e->{
        try {
            ObservableList<Integer> oList=listView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndices();
            if(oList.size()!=0){
                outputFromClient.writeObject(oList.size());
                outputFromClient.flush();
                outputFromClient.writeObject(tf.getText());
                outputFromClient.flush();
                for (Integer i:listView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndices())
                { 
                  outputFromClient.writeObject(i);
                  outputFromClient.flush();
                }

            }else{
                outputFromClient.writeObject(0);
                outputFromClient.flush();
                outputFromClient.writeObject(tf.getText());
                outputFromClient.flush();
            }
            tf.setText("");
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }



    });

    try {
        socket=new Socket("localhost",8000);
        inputFromServer=new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        outputFromClient=new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        new handleMessagesFromServer().start();
    }catch(SocketException ee){
        ta.appendText("Problem with socket\n");
        try{
            socket.close();
        }catch(IOException e2){
            System.out.println("can't close client's socket,in client class");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

}




public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);

}
class handleMessagesFromServer extends Thread{

    public void run(){
        while(true){
            String textFromServer;
            try {
                textFromServer = (String)inputFromServer.readObject();
                if(textFromServer.equals("#"))//sign that we need to modify ListView
                {
                    int nSize=(Integer)inputFromServer.readObject();
                    for(int i=0;i<nSize;i++){
                        String aName=(String)inputFromServer.readObject();
                        if(!(listView.getItems().contains(aName))){
                        listView.getItems().add(aName);
                        }
                    }

                }else{//just a simple text
                Platform.runLater(()->{
                ta.appendText(textFromServer);
            });
                }
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException | IOException e) {
                //e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("here");
            }
        }

    }

}
}
```

Exception:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-4" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread; currentThread = Thread-4 
at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.checkFxUserThread(Toolkit.java:236‌​) 
at java.util.AbstractList.add(Unknown Source) 
at chat.Client$handleMessagesFromServer.run(Client.java:154)
```

Comment: _"console shows error"_ -- do you think maybe it might be necessary to tell us what the error is?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

Comment: I am sorry.here is the error i get: Exception in thread "Thread-4" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread; currentThread = Thread-4
 at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.checkFxUserThread(Toolkit.java:236)
 at java.util.AbstractList.add(Unknown Source)
 at chat.Client$handleMessagesFromServer.run(Client.java:154)

Answer (score 0):

`listView.getItems().add(aName);` needs to be in a call `Platform.runlater;`.   But you should just follow the exception to the line in code and figure it out.

In this case it's telling you that you're "Not on FX application thread" which means you're modifying the scene from another thread.  You already have `Platform.runLater(()->{ta.appendText(textFromServer);});`, it's the same thing.